# How to automate inserting fields inside a text file?

Tags: perl, automation

Let's say you have a bunch of files containing lines such as the following :

```
{yellow_forest_ant|monsters_insects:2|Yellow forest ant|forestant||5|||10|100|||2|2|15||insect|||||||||};
{small_rabid_dog|monsters_dogs:1|Small rabid dog|forestdog||6|||10|90|||2|2|||canine|||||||||};
```

And you want to insert three fields between the 5th and 6th field, where some of the new content depends on what the existing fields are.

How would you do that in an automated way? 
Inserting some dynamic content inside lines of an existing text file.

My solution (in Perl):

```
while(<>) {
  if (/\{(.+?)\};/) {
    my @v= $1 =~ /([^\|\{\}]*?|\{\{.*?\}\})\|/g;
    my @output= (@v[0..4], guessMonsterClass($v[1]), $uniques{$v[0]}, '',@v[5..24]);
    print '{'.join('|',@output)."|};\n";
  } else { print; }
}
```

While my solution works, it doesn't work very well.
Improvements please!

Comment: Just take the string inside of the curly brackets, split it on `/\|/`, change the elements of the resulting array, join the changed array on `'|'` and write to output.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `xml`? I see no XML-related content.

Answer (score 1):

If your input does not contain escaped vertical bar, you can just use `split` and `splice`:

```
while (<>) {
    if (/\{(.+?)\};/) {
        my @v = split /\|/, $1, -1;
        splice @v, 5, 0, guessMonsterClass($v[1]), $uniques{$v[0]}, '';
        print '{', join('|', @v), "};\n";
    } else {
        print;
    }
}
```

Note the usage of -1 as LIMIT for `split` to keep the empty fields at the end. All the empty fields are captured, therefore you do not need to add an extra vertical bar in `print`.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the curly wink (`{};`), name your fields (complete, reasonable):

```
F1|F2|F3|F4|F5|F6
yellow_forest_ant|monsters_insects:2|"Yellow forest ant"|forestant||5
small_rabid_dog|monsters_dogs:1|"Small rabid dog"|forestdog||6
```

Use [DBI](http://p3rl.org/DBI) and [DBD::CSV](http://p3rl.org/DBD::CSV).

```
  my $dbh = DBI->connect( 'dbi:CSV:', "", "", {
        f_dir        => "../data"
      , csv_sep_char => '|'
      , PrintError   => 0
      , RaiseError   => 1
    });

  my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM monsters.txt');
  $sth->execute;
  while(my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    print '|', join( '|', @row ), "|\n";
  }

  $sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE monsters.txt SET F5 = F6 * 2 WHERE F4 = 'forestant'");
  $sth->execute;

  $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM monsters.txt');
  $sth->execute;
  while(my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    print '|', join( '|', @row ), "|\n";
  }
```

output:

```
|yellow_forest_ant|monsters_insects:2|Yellow forest ant|forestant||5|
|small_rabid_dog|monsters_dogs:1|Small rabid dog|forestdog||6|
|yellow_forest_ant|monsters_insects:2|Yellow forest ant|forestant|10|5|
|small_rabid_dog|monsters_dogs:1|Small rabid dog|forestdog||6|
```

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you to handle it using awk.

http://search.cpan.org/search?query=awk&mode=all

Comment: Why would you suggest that? (add your answer to this question to your post)